# How to programatically verify a file signature?

Tags: certificates, hash, windows, digital-signature, c++

I have a dll file signed with my private key, here is the signature info in Windows Explorer:

[image: Windows signature details on test.dll]

Now, using the public key found in the certificate, how can I verify the integrity of the file?

[image: Image of my signing certificate]

I am shipping the exe to the client and need the exe to verify its own signature at startup. Which c++ API or Windows default commands can I use to implement this?

Comment: This is a very unconventional way to use digital signatures. "Decrypting the signature to get the hash" may work in this case because it's RSA, but it wouldn't work with any other signature algorithm. If you have the file and you're trying to get the hash, why not just hash the file? Basically, can you explain what you're trying to accomplish, because right now this seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: No i am going to hash the file again and compare it with the hash decrypted from the message digest.This is to make sure that the application is not affected with some malicious payload

Comment: I see. If you Google for "how to verify an rsa signature" you'll get plenty of articles, most of which are pretty mathy because, well, this is tricky to do properly. Why not use a pre-built `RSA_verify()` from a library like openssl or libsodium?

Comment: Ok, I'm getting closer to understanding your question. But, ... you want your exe to verify its own signature (ie the file `test.exe` checks the signature on `test.exe`)?

Comment: Yes .In the main function I am planning to verify its own signature .

Comment: I have already found a method to verify the signature. we can use windows WinVerifyTrust() to achieve it. now i would like to verify the hash as well

Comment: Maybe you should do some reading about how signatures work. Verifying the signature does verify the hash. In fact, that's exactly what verifying a signature does.

Comment: WinVerifyTrust works in the manner that it verifies the certificate against trusted certificates found in windows certificate store. It is not checking the hash

Comment: I would caution that "self-verifying EXEs" don't give you as much security as you think; an attacker who is moderately skilled with reverse-engineering can modify your file, re-sign it with their own certificate, and then replace the certificate that's embedded in the exe. The better approach is to get a publicly-trusted code signing certificate from a public CA so that the Windows OS can verify the signature for you.

Comment: I am not only checking the executable file’s signature. I am checking the linked dll’s signatures as well. I have restricted the scope for this question.

Answer (score 5):

With all due respect, you are trying to reinvent the wheel for something that you don't understand very well. You are trying to hand-roll your own RSA signature verification code so that your app can verify its own signature at startup.

This is a solved problem through the Windows Code Signing system. What you should do is [buy a proper code signing certificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate) so that Windows automatically verifies the signature on your app every time it is run:

[image: Windows code signing dialog box]

Crypto is very tricky and hard to get right, so I highly advise you to use the built-in Windows mechanisms rather than trying to do this from scratch.

Comment: "buy a certificate" or use a free certificate from [lets encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I created a tool that uses Windows CryptAPI and WintrustAPI to verifiy signatures.
It is built as a GUI with some management capabilities.
It is open-source, you can get executables and source code here:

https://github.com/inamozov/SigInfoGUI

Maybe this code will help you to better understand how Wintrust and CryptAPI works in Windows